# React Material UI Autocomplete with custom dropdown and Add Button on the bottom

Tags: javascript, reactjs, autocomplete, material-ui

I would like to create autocomplete in React [Material-ui](https://mui.com/) with a custom dropdown where on the bottom where it would be a button Add New Element.

[image]

I tried a few solutions, but there was always a problem to keep the button after the search.
Anyone has any idea how to do it? If not do you know any other plugin which can do that.

Please check clean code here.
https://codesandbox.io/s/pensive-grothendieck-g7eyg?file=/src/App.js

Comment: did you try createable option in MUi autocomplete. User can add custom option if he do not find any relevant option. https://mui.com/components/autocomplete/#FreeSoloCreateOption.js

Comment: @muzamil301 thanks that is correct solution

Comment: @muzamil301 I can't or I don't know how to do it. Please send me a link how can I do it.

Comment: there will be a tick mark just click on that tick to mark  that comment as answer

Comment: @muzamil301 I don't have It. I think you made comment instead of that you should make answare.

Comment: let me add answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you try creatable option in Material UI autocomplete. User can add custom option if he do not find any relevant option.

[Materialui autocomplete adding custom option to autocomplete dropdown](http://mui.com/components/autocomplete/#FreeSoloCreateOption.js)

Answer (score 6):

You could add a paper component as a prop to the Autocomplete component

```
<Autocomplete
    ...
    PaperComponent={({ children }) => {
      return (
        <Paper>
          {children}
          <Button
            color="primary"
            fullWidth
            sx={{ justifyContent: "flex-start", pl: 2 }}
            onMouseDown={() => {
              console.log("Add new");
            }}
          >
            + Add New
          </Button>
        </Paper>
      );
    }}
  />
```

Link to Codesandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/autocomplete-with-button-in-dropdown-g5f782

Answer (score 0):

You can try to add `const data = [...universityList, {name: Add new}]` and pass it on to your options props in Autocomplete.